# Add a separate filter for items that are already listed in a sidebar, but not explicitly as a filter?

Tags: filter, grid, sidebar

I have a question regarding a filter.

I have a grid with cards that represent pages in a document. There are rules for these cards about when they should be displayed and when not in a generated product. The Rules are located in a sidebar on the left, to get an overview of all existing rules and to edit them. When I click on a rule in the sidebar on the left, I can edit a rule in a modal. Additionally, I can drag and drop these rules onto selected cards.

I need a filter that shows the rules, to sort cards according to rules, so that I can  specifically edit or check them easily and fast. (for example)

In reality, there can be up to 150 cards or more with about 20 or more rules

**Now to my question: Does it make sense to add a separate filter above (or anywhere else in another shape) or is there a way to integrate it/combine it with the existing items in the sidebar?**

I really would love to hear your ideas/arguments both for and against.

[image]

If you don't want to get influenced by my thoughts, stop here:

Pro filter above:

- it's feels a bit more learned and more explicit to have it like an own element above the grid
- it's not mixing up with primary item actions like "edit" on click
- it's consistent to other scenarios, where the items on the left are not filterable
- it's easy to make this sticky and you always see all items (or add a functionality to show more/less filter-items)
- you have to scroll if the end of the sidebar is reached

Contra to have it as an own element above the grid:

- it's a bit redundant, since the exact same rules are already on the left in the sidebar
- an extra element is a bit more cluttered and could be confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest adding the filter on the sidebar, but I think it to be very clear for your filter to add an `i` icon and write a small message that leads to your idea, now when your filter is open I suggest opening it in a popup to have more space and more message to explain yourself

everything can be helpful for the user just if you make this point

- a good user story
- `i` icon to explain every section and give an example
- to be pointy in every section

**because you have the search on the sidebar so I think you need to put the filter under the search, and that will help you to use the rest of the screen just to show data and to add more features, yes I think you need to open the filter in a modal or popup this will help you to make and create a good UI filter**

good lock

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and thoughts! Really! I was wondering, if the filter should be placed in some way near the grid because it will affect the grid. I really like the idea of open it in a popup or modal. What do you think?

Comment: @Kai i update my answer, please check

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.